# How to prevent composer to remove bin/magento?

Tags: magento2, php, composer

When I use composer to add a package, it deletes a bunch of packages, and **it deletes the bin/magento** .

How to prevent composer to delete bin/magento ?

How can I have everything working like before the installation, but with another added package?

.

Here is the command I run, and the beginning of what it outputs

```
www/magento2$ composer require pmclain/module-stripe

Using version ^1.1 for pmclain/module-stripe
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 40 installs, 58 updates, 124 removals
  - Removing magento/module-sales-sequence (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\SalesSequence
  - Removing magento/module-require-js (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\RequireJs
  - Removing magento/module-bundle-import-export (100.1.4)
Removing Magento\BundleImportExport
  - Removing magento/module-sample-data (100.1.4)
Removing Magento\SampleData
  - Removing magento/module-cache-invalidate (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\CacheInvalidate
  - Removing magento/module-configurable-import-export (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\ConfigurableImportExport
  - Removing magento/module-grouped-import-export (100.1.2)
Removing Magento\GroupedImportExport
  - Removing magento/module-layered-navigation (100.1.2)
Removing Magento\LayeredNavigation
  - Removing magento/module-offline-payments (100.1.2)
Removing Magento\OfflinePayments
  - Removing magento/module-swagger (100.1.2)
Removing Magento\Swagger
  - Removing magento/module-swatches-layered-navigation (100.1.2)
Removing Magento\SwatchesLayeredNavigation
  - Removing magento/module-version (100.1.2)
Removing Magento\Version
  - Removing magento/module-webapi-security (100.1.2)
Removing Magento\WebapiSecurity
  - Removing magento/theme-adminhtml-backend (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\ThemeAdminhtmlBackend
  - Removing magento/theme-frontend-blank (100.1.7)
Removing Magento\ThemeFrontendBlank
  - Removing magento/theme-frontend-luma (100.1.7)
Removing Magento\ThemeFrontendLuma
  - Removing magento/module-wishlist-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\WishlistSampleData
  - Removing magento/module-widget-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\WidgetSampleData
  - Removing magento/module-theme-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\ThemeSampleData
  - Removing magento/module-tax-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\TaxSampleData
  - Removing magento/module-swatches-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\SwatchesSampleData
  - Removing magento/module-sales-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\SalesSampleData
  - Removing magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\SalesRuleSampleData
  - Removing magento/module-review-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\ReviewSampleData
  - Removing magento/module-product-links-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\ProductLinksSampleData
  - Removing magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\OfflineShippingSampleData
  - Removing magento/module-msrp-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\MsrpSampleData
  - Removing magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\GroupedProductSampleData
  - Removing magento/module-customer-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\CustomerSampleData
  - Removing magento/module-configurable-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\ConfigurableSampleData
  - Removing magento/module-catalog-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\CatalogSampleData
  - Removing magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\CatalogRuleSampleData
  - Removing magento/module-bundle-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\BundleSampleData
Removing Magento\ProductCommunityEdition
  - Removing magento/module-weee (100.1.2)
Removing Magento\Weee
  - Removing magento/module-webapi (100.1.5)
Removing Magento\Webapi
  - Removing magento/module-usps (100.1.4)
Removing Magento\Usps
  - Removing magento/module-ups (100.1.4)
Removing Magento\Ups
  - Removing magento/module-translation (100.1.4)
Removing Magento\Translation
  - Removing magento/module-tax-import-export (100.1.2)
Removing Magento\TaxImportExport
  - Removing magento/module-swatches (100.1.10)
Removing Magento\Swatches
  - Removing magento/module-sitemap (100.1.5)
Removing Magento\Sitemap
  - Removing magento/module-send-friend (100.1.2)
Removing Magento\SendFriend
  - Removing magento/module-sales-inventory (100.1.1)
Removing Magento\SalesInventory
  - Removing magento/module-robots (100.1.0)
Removing Magento\Robots
  - Removing magento/module-product-video (100.1.8)
Removing Magento\ProductVideo
  - Removing magento/module-persistent (100.1.4)
Removing Magento\Persistent
  - Removing magento/module-offline-shipping (100.1.4)
Removing Magento\OfflineShipping
  - Removing magento/module-new-relic-reporting (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\NewRelicReporting
  - Removing magento/module-multishipping (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\Multishipping
  - Removing magento/module-marketplace (100.1.2)
Removing Magento\Marketplace
  - Removing magento/module-google-optimizer (100.1.2)
Removing Magento\GoogleOptimizer
  - Removing magento/module-google-analytics (100.1.2)
Removing Magento\GoogleAnalytics
  - Removing magento/module-google-adwords (100.1.2)
Removing Magento\GoogleAdwords
  - Removing magento/module-fedex (100.1.4)
Removing Magento\Fedex
  - Removing magento/module-encryption-key (100.1.2)
Removing Magento\EncryptionKey
  - Removing magento/module-downloadable-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\DownloadableSampleData
  - Removing magento/module-downloadable-import-export (100.1.2)
Removing Magento\DownloadableImportExport
  - Removing magento/module-dhl (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\Dhl
  - Removing magento/module-developer (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\Developer
  - Removing magento/module-deploy (100.1.6)
Removing Magento\Deploy
  - Removing magento/module-customer-import-export (100.1.5)
Removing Magento\CustomerImportExport
  - Removing magento/module-currency-symbol (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\CurrencySymbol
  - Removing magento/module-cookie (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\Cookie
  - Removing magento/module-cms-sample-data (100.1.0-rc2)
Removing Magento\CmsSampleData
  - Removing magento/module-checkout-agreements (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\CheckoutAgreements
  - Removing magento/module-catalog-widget (100.1.4)
Removing Magento\CatalogWidget
  - Removing magento/module-search (100.1.4)
Removing Magento\Search
  - Removing magento/module-catalog-search (100.1.8)
Removing Magento\CatalogSearch
  - Removing magento/module-configurable-product (100.1.11)
Removing Magento\ConfigurableProduct
  - Removing magento/module-catalog-rule-configurable (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\CatalogRuleConfigurable
  - Removing magento/module-captcha (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\Captcha
  - Removing magento/module-bundle (100.1.6)
Removing Magento\Bundle
  - Removing magento/module-vault (100.2.2)
Removing Magento\Vault
  - Removing magento/module-paypal (100.1.8)
Removing Magento\Paypal
  - Removing magento/module-braintree (100.1.8)
Removing Magento\Braintree
  - Removing magento/module-authorizenet (100.1.6)
Removing Magento\Authorizenet
  - Removing magento/module-contact (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\Contact
  - Removing magento/module-gift-message (100.1.4)
Removing Magento\GiftMessage
  - Removing magento/module-security (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\Security
  - Removing magento/module-rss (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\Rss
  - Removing magento/module-cms-url-rewrite (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\CmsUrlRewrite
  - Removing magento/module-user (100.1.4)
Removing Magento\User
  - Removing magento/module-reports (100.1.6)
Removing Magento\Reports
  - Removing magento/module-grouped-product (100.1.4)
Removing Magento\GroupedProduct
  - Removing magento/module-downloadable (100.1.4)
Removing Magento\Downloadable
  - Removing magento/module-cron (100.1.4)
Removing Magento\Cron
  - Removing magento/module-variable (100.1.2)
Removing Magento\Variable
  - Removing magento/module-email (100.1.6)
Removing Magento\Email
  - Removing magento/module-shipping (100.1.5)
Removing Magento\Shipping
  - Removing magento/module-sales-rule (100.1.6)
Removing Magento\SalesRule
  - Removing magento/module-payment (100.1.8)
Removing Magento\Payment
  - Removing magento/module-rule (100.1.7)
Removing Magento\Rule
  - Removing magento/module-sales (100.1.10)
Removing Magento\Sales
  - Removing magento/module-review (100.1.5)
Removing Magento\Review
  - Removing magento/module-newsletter (100.1.5)
Removing Magento\Newsletter
  - Removing magento/module-integration (100.1.6)
Removing Magento\Integration
  - Removing magento/module-authorization (100.1.2)
Removing Magento\Authorization
  - Removing magento/module-wishlist (100.1.7)
Removing Magento\Wishlist
  - Removing magento/module-widget (100.1.6)
Removing Magento\Widget
  - Removing magento/module-url-rewrite (100.1.4)
Removing Magento\UrlRewrite
  - Removing magento/module-ui (100.1.9)
Removing Magento\Ui
  - Removing magento/module-theme (100.1.9)
Removing Magento\Theme
  - Removing magento/module-tax (100.1.4)
Removing Magento\Tax
  - Removing magento/module-quote (100.1.7)
Removing Magento\Quote
  - Removing magento/module-product-alert (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\ProductAlert
  - Removing magento/module-page-cache (100.1.5)
Removing Magento\PageCache
  - Removing magento/module-msrp (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\Msrp
  - Removing magento/module-indexer (100.1.5)
Removing Magento\Indexer
  - Removing magento/module-directory (100.1.5)
Removing Magento\Directory
  - Removing magento/module-config (100.1.7)
Removing Magento\Config
  - Removing magento/module-cms (101.0.9)
Removing Magento\Cms
  - Removing magento/module-checkout (100.1.10)
Removing Magento\Checkout
  - Removing magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite (100.1.5)
Removing Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite
  - Removing magento/module-catalog-rule (100.1.5)
Removing Magento\CatalogRule
  - Removing magento/module-import-export (100.1.6)
Removing Magento\ImportExport
  - Removing magento/module-eav (100.1.8)
Removing Magento\Eav
  - Removing magento/module-customer (100.1.10)
Removing Magento\Customer
  - Removing magento/module-catalog-inventory (100.1.7)
Removing Magento\CatalogInventory
  - Removing magento/module-catalog-import-export (100.1.8)
Removing Magento\CatalogImportExport
  - Removing magento/module-catalog (101.0.11)
Removing Magento\Catalog
  - Removing magento/module-advanced-pricing-import-export (100.1.3)
Removing Magento\AdvancedPricingImportExport
  - Removing magento/magento2-base (2.1.11)
Removing Magento\Magento2Base
  - Removing magento/framework (100.1.11)
Removing Magento\Framework
```

(and after, composer installs and updates packages)

composer.json

```
{
"name": "magento/magento2ce",
"description": "Magento 2 (Open Source)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.2.3",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"require": {
    "php": "7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0",
    "zendframework/zend-stdlib": "^2.7.7",
    "zendframework/zend-code": "~3.1.0",
    "zendframework/zend-server": "^2.6.1",
    "zendframework/zend-soap": "^2.6.0",
    "zendframework/zend-uri": "^2.5.1",
    "zendframework/zend-validator": "^2.6.0",
    "zendframework/zend-crypt": "^2.6.0",
    "zendframework/zend-console": "^2.6.0",
    "zendframework/zend-modulemanager": "^2.7",
    "zendframework/zend-mvc": "~2.7.12",
    "zendframework/zend-text": "^2.6.0",
    "zendframework/zend-i18n": "^2.7.3",
    "zendframework/zend-eventmanager": "^2.6.3",
    "zendframework/zend-view": "^2.8.1",
    "zendframework/zend-servicemanager": "^2.7.8",
    "zendframework/zend-json": "^2.6.1",
    "zendframework/zend-config": "^2.6.0",
    "zendframework/zend-form": "^2.10.0",
    "zendframework/zend-di": "^2.6.1",
    "zendframework/zend-serializer": "^2.7.2",
    "zendframework/zend-log": "^2.9.1",
    "zendframework/zend-http": "^2.6.0",
    "zendframework/zend-db": "^2.8.2",
    "zendframework/zend-captcha": "^2.7.1",
    "zendframework/zend-session": "^2.7.3",
    "magento/zendframework1": "~1.13.0",
    "colinmollenhour/credis": "1.8.2",
    "colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract": "1.3.4",
    "colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis": "1.10.4",
    "colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file": "1.4",
    "composer/composer": "1.4.1",
    "monolog/monolog": "^1.17",
    "oyejorge/less.php": "~1.7.0",
    "pelago/emogrifier": "1.2.0",
    "tubalmartin/cssmin": "4.1.1",
    "magento/magento-composer-installer": ">=0.1.11",
    "braintree/braintree_php": "3.27.0",
    "symfony/console": "~2.3, !=2.7.0",
    "symfony/event-dispatcher": "~2.1",
    "symfony/process": "~2.1",
    "phpseclib/phpseclib": "2.0.*",
    "tedivm/jshrink": "~1.3.0",
    "magento/composer": "~1.2.0",
    "lib-libxml": "*",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-gd": "*",
    "ext-spl": "*",
    "ext-dom": "*",
    "ext-simplexml": "*",
    "ext-mcrypt": "*",
    "ext-hash": "*",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "ext-intl": "*",
    "ext-xsl": "*",
    "ext-mbstring": "*",
    "ext-openssl": "*",
    "ext-zip": "*",
    "ext-pdo_mysql": "*",
    "ext-soap": "*",
    "sjparkinson/static-review": "~4.1",
    "ramsey/uuid": "3.7.3",
    "pmclain/module-stripe": "^1.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.2.2",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.2.0",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.4"
},
"replace": {
    "magento/module-marketplace": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-admin-notification": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-advanced-pricing-import-export": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-analytics": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-authorization": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-authorizenet": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-backend": "100.2.3",
    "magento/module-backup": "100.2.2",
    "magento/module-braintree": "100.2.3",
    "magento/module-bundle": "100.2.2",
    "magento/module-bundle-import-export": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-cache-invalidate": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-captcha": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-catalog": "102.0.3",
    "magento/module-catalog-analytics": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-catalog-import-export": "100.2.2",
    "magento/module-catalog-inventory": "100.2.2",
    "magento/module-catalog-rule": "101.0.2",
    "magento/module-catalog-rule-configurable": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-catalog-search": "100.2.2",
    "magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite": "100.2.2",
    "magento/module-catalog-widget": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-checkout": "100.2.3",
    "magento/module-checkout-agreements": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-cms": "102.0.3",
    "magento/module-cms-url-rewrite": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-config": "101.0.3",
    "magento/module-configurable-import-export": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-configurable-product": "100.2.3",
    "magento/module-configurable-product-sales": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-contact": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-cookie": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-cron": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-currency-symbol": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-customer": "101.0.3",
    "magento/module-customer-analytics": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-customer-import-export": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-deploy": "100.2.2",
    "magento/module-developer": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-dhl": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-directory": "100.2.2",
    "magento/module-downloadable": "100.2.2",
    "magento/module-downloadable-import-export": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-eav": "101.0.2",
    "magento/module-email": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-encryption-key": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-fedex": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-gift-message": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-google-adwords": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-google-analytics": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-google-optimizer": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-grouped-import-export": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-grouped-product": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-import-export": "100.2.3",
    "magento/module-indexer": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-instant-purchase": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-integration": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-layered-navigation": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-media-storage": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-msrp": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-multishipping": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-new-relic-reporting": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-newsletter": "100.2.2",
    "magento/module-offline-payments": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-offline-shipping": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-page-cache": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-payment": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-paypal": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-persistent": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-product-alert": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-product-video": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-quote": "101.0.2",
    "magento/module-quote-analytics": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-release-notification": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-reports": "100.2.3",
    "magento/module-require-js": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-review": "100.2.3",
    "magento/module-review-analytics": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-robots": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-rss": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-rule": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-sales": "101.0.2",
    "magento/module-sales-analytics": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-sales-inventory": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-sales-rule": "101.0.1",
    "magento/module-sales-sequence": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-sample-data": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-search": "100.2.2",
    "magento/module-security": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-send-friend": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-shipping": "100.2.3",
    "magento/module-signifyd": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-sitemap": "100.2.2",
    "magento/module-store": "100.2.2",
    "magento/module-swagger": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-swatches": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-swatches-layered-navigation": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-tax": "100.2.3",
    "magento/module-tax-import-export": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-theme": "100.2.3",
    "magento/module-translation": "100.2.2",
    "magento/module-ui": "101.0.3",
    "magento/module-ups": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-url-rewrite": "101.0.2",
    "magento/module-user": "101.0.1",
    "magento/module-usps": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-variable": "100.2.2",
    "magento/module-vault": "101.0.1",
    "magento/module-version": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-webapi": "100.2.1",
    "magento/module-webapi-security": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-weee": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-widget": "101.0.1",
    "magento/module-wishlist": "101.0.1",
    "magento/module-wishlist-analytics": "100.2.0",
    "magento/theme-adminhtml-backend": "100.2.1",
    "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.2.1",
    "magento/theme-frontend-luma": "100.2.2",
    "magento/language-de_de": "100.2.0",
    "magento/language-en_us": "100.2.0",
    "magento/language-es_es": "100.2.0",
    "magento/language-fr_fr": "100.2.0",
    "magento/language-nl_nl": "100.2.0",
    "magento/language-pt_br": "100.2.0",
    "magento/language-zh_hans_cn": "100.2.0",
    "magento/framework": "101.0.3",
    "trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon": "1.4.3",
    "components/jquery": "1.11.0",
    "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "5.6.14",
    "components/jqueryui": "1.10.4",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "3.1.0",
    "tinymce/tinymce": "3.4.7"
},
"extra": {
    "component_paths": {
        "trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon": "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
        "components/jquery": [
            "lib/web/jquery.js",
            "lib/web/jquery/jquery.min.js",
            "lib/web/jquery/jquery-migrate.js"
        ],
        "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "lib/web/jquery/fileUploader",
        "components/jqueryui": [
            "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui.js"
        ],
        "twbs/bootstrap": [
            "lib/web/jquery/jquery.tabs.js"
        ],
        "tinymce/tinymce": "lib/web/tiny_mce"
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": [
            "app/code/"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ],
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "**/dev/**",
        "**/update/**",
        "**/Test/**"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```